# Why is the mean of the means not equal to the grand mean (average)?

Tags: mean, excel

I'm using Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2302 Build 16.0.16130.20374) 32-bit

I have 31 numbers from 6 different centers.
I need an average for each center and an average for all.
If all 31 numbers are averaged together in col A, using =AVERAGE(A1:A31) I get 104.
Center 1 average was 156
Center 2 average was 194
Center 3 average was 100
Center 4 average was 59
Center 5 average was -70
Center 6 average was 125

The individual averages looked wonky, so to double check I tried averaging those 6 totals and got 94 instead of 104. I know there is some rounding but I didn't expect a difference of 10.

I tried it with numbers from different departments within the same 6 centers and the averages equaled each other.

[These averages were fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz98M.png)
[Why are these averages different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afF6V.png)

Comment: You can't take the average of average and expect it to equal the average of the totals. That is not how math works.

Comment: "I tried averaging those 6 totals" is that literally what you did?  It's difficult to tell from your screenshots

Comment: did you weight that average by the number of values in each "center"?

Answer (score 19):

The average of averages is not the same as the grand average *if group sizes are different* (unless you have a very specific situation), which it very much seems is the case here.

Suppose group 1 has two entries, 100 and 200. The average is 150. Next, suppose group 2 has a single entry, 250. Its average thus is also 250. The average of averages is 200. However, the overall average is 183.

If you want to average averages in a way to obtain the overall average, you need to weight each "sub-average" by the number of entries in the group.

Comment: The weighted mean is explained nicely here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Mathematical_definition. Here $w_i$ is the number of entries for center $i$ and $x_i$ is the average for center $i$.